# Curve fitting with specified behavior at endpoints

Tags: python, curve-fitting, modeling

I have been looking for a function / class of models that have the following behavior:

1. Smoothing where I have data-points
2. At lower bounds, start asymptotically approaching some value Y_low
3. At higher bound, start asymptotically approaching some valye Y_high
   (Y_low, and Y_high are user specified)

In the following example, we see the behavior (currently modeled with a UnivariateSpline via Scipy with a knot specified at 0.1)

Where we have datapoints), orange dots, we use a spline to do some smoothing.  Once we get to the higher bound, X>0.3, we see the fit shooting off!  Which is somewhat undesirable.

We would much rather have it..."turn" and smoothly approach some value.
On the lower end side, we would want the fit to smoothly approach 0.  (hard to see without zooming in).

[image: Example Graph]

Is there a way to specify this type of constraint?

Current approaches that had additional undesired behaviors:

1. Insert a boatload of datapoints at the edges to "force" the curve. This led to some undesired oscillation behaviors.
   ie - add datapoint (0.4, 0.4) * 1000 to this graph.
2. Modeling the line with a sigmoid/logistic curve (something s-shaped) but this doesn't converge / fit most of the time.
3. Scipy Cubic Spline - with clamped ends -- it overfit the data.

Any help or just ideas is appreciated!

Comment: Isn't that piecewise anyway. So you could just add a beginning and and continuous and differentiable to do the job.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How do you actually fit, as you have x and y errors.

Comment: @mikuszefski the error bars are for show.  The orange dots are merely the average of "bins" -- and used to fit my line.  The binning of the data, while it introduces errors of its own provides slightly better behavior so far...

Comment: Concerning the desired behaviour. If you make your own b-spline fit. with non-doubling (equidistant )points and one knot over the end data point, you'll have one spline having a maximum at that knot. If you neglect the next inner spline, no additional slope or offset is added, such that the spline fit will generate a function with zero slope and constant value. You then can just continue piece wise. The best  knot distribution is a different thing, though.